# Confused with DataGrid editing in WPF

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, datagrid

I'm a newbie in WPF working on a C# project. I have a `DataGrid` `TwoWay` binded to a `DataTable` with 3 editable columns. When the user finishes editing a value in the `DataGrid`, I can do something with the change by processing the events `DataTable.RowChanged` and `DataTable.ColumnChanged`.

The values in both the `DataGrid` and the `DataTable` seem to change only when the selected row of the `DataGrid` changes. The problem is, when the user edits 2 values in the same Row at the same time, I get confusing values in the `DataTable`: the 2nd edited value is modified while the first edited one isn't. I tried other ways to get 2 correct values like processing the events `DataGrid.CellEditEnding` and `DataGrid.CurrentCellChanged` but I failed finally.

If I didn't make myself clear (English is not my mother language :) ), here's an example. The user double-click the cell `r1c1` to edit it, and then double-click `r1c2`. The values I get in the `DataTable` are the unedited value in `r1c1` and  the edited value in `r1c2`...

Here's my XAML code:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="xxx" ......
          AutoGenerateColumns="False"
          BeginningEdit="xxxEditBegin"
          CellEditEnding="xxxEditEnd"
          CurrentCellChanged="xxxCellChg"
          ColumnHeaderStyle="{StaticResource DataGridColumnHeaderStyle}"
          RowStyle="{StaticResource DataGridRowStyle}"
          CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridCellStyle}">
    ......
</DataGrid>

    <Style x:Key="DataGridCellStyle" TargetType="DataGridCell">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="DataGridCell">
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                        <DataGridDetailsPresenter HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Center" Content="{TemplateBinding Content}"/>
                    </Grid>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
        <Style.Triggers>
            ......
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

the other 2 styles only contain triggers ad setters.

I'm so confused and I appreciate any help :)

Comment: post code and we'll help

Comment: Did you try using both `CellEditEnding` and `CurrentCellChanged` events, as described in [WPF DataGrid - Committing Changes Cell-By-Cell](http://www.scottlogic.com/blog/2009/01/21/wpf-datagrid-committing-changes-cell-by-cell.html)?

Comment: I tried this and got 2 unedited values. @KarlAnderson

Comment: I thought of a solution after reading the article. CommitEdit() works  :) thanks @KarlAnderson

Comment: @user2594672 - Awesome, always great when you can fix your own problems.